What is "linear holding"?
In a Lisbon RNAV procedure, the LOST COMM box mentions "LINEAR HOLDING".
What are the purpose of this instruction during approaches?

Linear holding (LH) is a holding technique consisting in extending an arrival route instead of flying a racetrack pattern. Currently the LH flavor deployed, including for Lisbon arrivals, is a flexible vectoring, the point merge system (PMS):

Source.
In the normal case, the aircraft is directed to the merge point, a point on the route ahead, usually a fix from the approach procedure. When the aircraft needs to be delayed, it starts flying an additional arc of circle centered on the merge point. When the spacing with the previous aircraft is adequate, direct navigation to the merge point is resumed:

Source, modified.
The number of entry points can be varied, 1, 2 like above, or more. Aircraft flying different arc lengths for spacing requirements:

Source: Youtube, Ethiopan ATCA.
From SKYbrary:

Linear holding can be designed into an RNAV STAR. It allows ATC to delay, sequence, and integrate aircraft arrivals by giving routings along predeﬁned variable legs to speciﬁc points, instead of providing radar headings. It can also entirely replace or signiﬁcantly reduce the need for traditional holding stacks.


‘Point Merge’, shown below, is a particular type of linear hold that is already in operational use at some airports. ATC arrival clearance is given for the complete longest linear hold route. As the correct spacing is achieved, the aircraft is instructed to route to the ‘merge point’ from where a single arrival path is resumed.

LH (PMS flavor) is already implemented at several terminal areas in Europe and Eastern countries, to optimize the management of their dense and growing traffic:

Source.
LH is useful for performance based navigation (PBN) and continuous descent (CDA). The flow is more predictable. It contributes to reducing the total flight time, noise and fuel consumption. LH is used for small corrections in the sequencing (e.g. up to 5 minutes). Longer delays required by metered traffic (e.g. AMAN) is still based on racetracks or equivalent, prior to the LH.
This is also described in Portugal AIP, for arrivals at Lisbon:

ARRIVAL ROUTES LPPT RNAV Arrival Routes are based on the Point Merge System (PMS), a systematized method for sequencing arrival flows by merging inbound flows to a single point. All Point Merge Systems require a level segment on the PMS arc which may be considered as a linear hold. This means the linear hold will resemble an arc with the Merge Point (MP), at the centre of the arc.


While an aircraft is on the linear hold, it can be instructed by the controller to fly “Direct To” the MP, at any appropriate time, to shorten the trajectory rather than flying the entire PMS Arc. For each RWY there are two linear holding entry points: RWY02: MAZUK and ORTUG RWY20: EKLID and DEKKI. The MP for each RWY is coincident with the IF of the Instrument Approach Procedures RWY02/20.

More:

Point Merge implementation: A quick guide
New ATC procedures, unintended eﬀects on the ﬂight deck?
PMS from ATC side, 4 entry points on one runway, Youtube.


What a peculiar name for a pattern that consists of circling, arcs and a sector, but nothing linear

nicely put @Jpe61 !@

@Jpe61 The time on the arc allows to scale your time on the pattern linearly, unlike time (rounds) spent on a racetrack that has only discrete values

@Bergi ah, I see, derived from linear algebra then? Still a bit far fetched imo. Guess they had to find a term that would not be confused with something already used such as "arc", "continuous", "vector(ed)" etc.

@Jpe61 Just a guess. I have no idea about aviation.
